# How to use Apache Tomcat 8 in STS(Spring Tool Suite latest version)?

Tags: apache, configure, spring-tool-suite

Hi I am using STS of version 2.9.1. Now i want to upgrade to latest STS version and i want to use latest Apache Tomcat 8 Server. **Does latest STS support Apache Tomcat 8?**

Comment: Have you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004876/apache-tomcat-server-not-in-list-to-add-new)? It looks like it's the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does. You may need to download Tomcat 8 server runtime separately. Once you have the runtime, create Tomcat 8 Runtime Environment in STS/Eclipse via Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments and then when creating server instance via the Server view select the Tomcat 8 runtime environment.

Comment: Sorry, I am using STS 4 the latest version and I do not find any Tomcat server in the Runtime Environments section. It does not even have an Apache folder.

Comment: @flavio there is no Apache Tomcat in STS 4 
you have to install a plugin like **Eclipse JST Server Adapters (Apache Tomcat, JOnAS, J2EE)** from the Marketplace.

Answer (score 12):

There is no Apache Tomcat in Spring Tool Suite 4
you have to install a plugin like **[Eclipse JST Server Adapters (Apache Tomcat, JOnAS, J2EE)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-jst-server-adapters-apache-tomcat-jonas-j2ee#group-details)** from the Marketplace.

Comment: How to add Tomcat 8.5 support?

Comment: It is installed in the latest spring tool suite 4.1