# Apache Tomcat server not in list to add new

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I need to add an Apache Tomcat server but the "Apache" folder have only Geronimo servers.

How to fix this?

STS 4.0.0.0.M12

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The STS4 distribution doesn't contain those adapters out of the box, since we tried to reduce the overall size of the distribution for various reasons (reduced startup time, reduced size, etc.).

If you want to get the Apache Tomcat server adaptors back, you can install the `JST Server Adaptor...` features from the main Eclipse 2018-09 p2 repository via `Install New Software`, select the main Eclipse update site (the right one depends on the base Eclipse version that you have, but it will show up in the drop-down list for you, either the Eclipse Photon one or the Eclipse 2018-09 one), scroll down the list, expand the `Web...` category, and select the `JST...` features.

Answer (score 1):

In the STS 4.1 distribution the Apache Tomact server adaptor is added back.

Meanwhile, if you are using Maven, then you might have to install m2e WTP plugin as detailed here for "Run on Server" Option.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11090295/470347